# Distribution of iterated differences of a random binary sequence

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's start from a (uniformly) random sequence $(a_i)_{i=1}^n \subset \{0,1\}^n$ and calculate its difference sequence ($i$th term is $a_{i+1}-a_{i}$, for $i=1, \dots , n-1$). Let's iterate taking the difference $k$ times. We can assume we start with $n=k+1$ and end up with a single number. How likely do we end up with a certain value $y \in \{-2^{k-1}, \dots , 2^{k-1} \}$?

---

We notice that the probability of $y$ is proportional to the size of its inverse image in the map

$$p: \{0,1\}^{k+1} \to \mathbb{Z}, \space \space p(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (-1)^{k+i} { {k}\choose{i-1} } x_i$$

Here's the distribution for certain values of $k$, and [an applet where you can look at them more closely](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f7wem9e4q5) (**warning**: don't set $k$ too large, because it grows exponentially).

[image]

Notice how there is a regular pattern for some values of $k$: There are "spikes of 3" and these are somewhat regularly spaced (although in the case $k=11$ there are longer empty regions in between) For $k=9$ the spikes are lumped together, but in fact they still exists. Now, does this have anything to do with primes, I don't know but those cases seemed to me the most striking ones. The spikes like start from the origin where the highest one resides, then they oscillate and die off.

I have also written [this Python code](https://pastebin.pl/view/19435a98) to calculate the distribution somewhat more rapidly (although the size of the set of possible values grows fast, so it won't be able to handle very large cases any better than the brute force method). I also found [this OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A205536). It doesn't have the $-1$ but gives the same image. In fact if we forget the minus sign, it just translates the distribution by $2^{k-1}$